# How do I roll up values to create a list in the cells of a dataframe per id using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as shown below:

```
id  value
100 a
100 b
100 c
100 d
200 1
200 2
200 3
```

How do I roll up to the below format?

```
id  value
100 ['a','b','c','d']
200 ['1','2','3']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) on 'id' and then [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply) `list` to `value` column and then call [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index):

```
In [13]:

df.groupby('id')['value'].apply(list).reset_index()
Out[13]:
    id         value
0  100  [a, b, c, d]
1  200     [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I resolved this error by creating list of tuples ( i.e. apply(tuples)) instead of list. But i am not able to explain why tuples works here & when to use tuples vs list. Please advise.

Comment: If you have a new question then post a new question, SO is not a forum. The error is pretty self-explanatory the list dtype is not hashable so it won't work.